# How do I restore a gerrit code-review user that seems to have gotten corrupted due to a postgresql db migration?

Tags: gerrit

I have a corrupted user account and I can't figure out how to resolve it.

Environment:
Gerrit Code Review 2.14.1
Ubuntu 14.04
SAML SSO plugin is in use.

**How I got here:**
I shut down my gerrit instance and performed a postgresql 9.3 db dump of an entire gerrit database. I migrated that data to postgresql 9.5 on a new Ubuntu server. I used published methods by postgres to accomplish this. It went without error.
I reconfigured the //etc/gerrit.config file to point to this new postgesql server. 
I restarted gerrit successfully. At this point I'm able to see my own reviews, other folks reviews and pushed patch-sets, etc. However, to my dismay, all the other users are not known. All non-me patches that I can see in the gerrit dashboard are attributed to "Anonymous Coward (accountId)" where accountId is the actual gerrit account number that was assigned to that user on first-time use of the service.
While the service was up and pointing to that new db, a user nearby overheard my gasp and tried to hit the gerrit service. He was faced with a first-time user prompt. This was absolutely unexpected because I myself was not faced with this.

I began to unwind my changes. Basically, a quick edit to the gerrit.config file db entry to the former IP, and restarted.

Now, I can see that all of the user attributions are correct in the dashboard. Now that user tries again to hit Gerrit, but now he gets a 403. This is unexpected.

Worthy of note:
Our company uses SAML for SSO. I use TheSamet SAML plugin for Gerrit.
All of a user's metadata comes from the plant's LDAP via headers. When a new user is faced with the first-time user dialog, all the fields are pre-filled and immutable.

**Some Troubleshooting:**
Perusing the gerrit error_log reveals the following: (actual username scrubbed)

```
[2018-12-05 18:57:43,130] [ReceiveCommits-1] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.config.PluginConfigFactory : No /gerrit/etc/gitiles.config; assuming defaults
[2018-12-05 18:57:52,293] [HTTP-65] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.query.account.InternalAccountQuery : Ambiguous external ID gerrit:jdoefor accounts: 1000001, 1000004
[2018-12-05 18:57:52,311] [HTTP-65] ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.auth.container.HttpLoginServlet : Unable to authenticate user "jdoe"
com.google.gerrit.server.account.AccountException: Cannot assign external ID "gerrit:jdoe" to account 1000109; external ID already in use.
    at com.google.gerrit.server.account.AccountManager.create(AccountManager.java:237)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.account.AccountManager.authenticate(AccountManager.java:118)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.auth.container.HttpLoginServlet.doGet(HttpLoginServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:181)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.raw.StaticModule$PolyGerritFilter.doFilter(StaticModule.java:451)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.GetUserFilter.doFilter(GetUserFilter.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequireSslFilter.doFilter(RequireSslFilter.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.UniversalWebLoginFilter.doFilter(UniversalWebLoginFilter.java:74)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RunAsFilter.doFilter(RunAsFilter.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gwtexpui.server.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestMetricsFilter.doFilter(RequestMetricsFilter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy$1.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:133)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:135)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at com.thesamet.gerrit.plugins.saml.SamlWebFilter.doFilter(SamlWebFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I attempted to troubleshoot this further by using gsql as documented within Gerrit.

```
java -jar gerrit.war gsql -d /path/to/my/gerrit/instance
select * from accounts where account_id='1000001';  //this returns the user.
select * from accounts where account_id='1000004';  //this returns nil.
```

I can't see that offending user 1000004 in the accounts db. Now I'm even more confused.

Questions:

1. Can anyone advise where that user's account_id coming from?
2. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this so that I can resolve.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with Gerrit. [gerrit_bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=5090#c6). 
** Note that my experience was a slightly different manifestation and my workaround is slightly different than the author of the defect.

My workaround was the following:
1. Remove the entire /path/to/gerrit directory and utterly replace it with the snapshot you just took before performing the upgrade. If you didn't take a snapshot (with gerrit stopped) just before-hand, then you must skip this step.
2. Perform an offline manual re-index of the accounts and changes (see code section below). The latter may take a bit of time depending on how large your repo is.

```
java -jar /path/to/gerrit.war reindex --index accounts -d /path/to/gerrit
java -jar /path/to/gerrit.war reindex --index changes -d /path/to/gerrit
```

Example: 
Assuming the Gerrit installation is at /gerrit and the gerrit.war file is at /gerrit/bin

```
java -jar /gerrit/bin/gerrit.war reindex --index accounts -d /gerrit
```